# SASxport to R: Errors while reading XPT SAS file

Tags: r, sas, dataloader

Anyone knows how to ignore/skip error while getting SAS export format file into R?

```
require(SASxport)
asc = SASxport::read.xport("..\\LLCP2018.XPT_", keep = cols)
```

> #### Checking if the specified file has the appropriate header
>
> #### Extracting data file information...
>
> #### Reading the data file... ### Error in `[.data.frame`(ds, whichds) : undefined columns selected

I have plenty of columns and don't want to check one-by-one if it really exists.
Would like to ignore missing but there's no option within the function.

**EDIT**

Found an easy solution:

```
lu = SASxport::lookup.xport(xfile)
```

Now can probably choose from `lu$names` and intersect with `cols`. Still not every variables can be read but it's better.

But when I choose few columns (checked) I get another error unable to skip:

> **Error in if (any(tooLong)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**

Why this stops the reading process and returns null?

**EDIT 2**

Found workaround reading the same function but from different package:

```
asc <- foreign::read.xport(xfile)
```

Works, unfortunately, loads whole data - if there's some size limitation probably nothing I could do.

Comment: Hard to tell what the question is.  Are you saying you have a list of VARIABLE names that you want to pass to the read.xport function so that it only keeps those variables when making the R object?  But some of the names in your list are not actually in the SAS xport file?

Comment: Some of variables shown in lookup can't be read due to first error (not found - but verbose doesn't say which), some other due to missing values (says which, but don't know how to continue reading)